# Using FINDSTR to set variables in FOR Loop

Tags: windows, batch-file

(EDITED) How can I read data from a text file and assign certain parts of it to variables?  In the lines below, for example, I want to assign the data to variables where indicated but ignore the header line, the preface word "DATA:" and any quotation marks.

```
HEADER (ignore)
  DATA:  "set text inside quotes to VAR1"
  DATA:  "set text inside quotes to VAR2"
  DATA (etc.)
```

The code I'm using is:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set COUNT=0
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("data.txt") do (
  set "INPUT=%%a"
  set /a COUNT=!COUNT!+1
  echo !INPUT! | findstr /i /c:"HEADER" > nul 
  if errorlevel 1 (
    set "INPUT=!INPUT:DATA:=!"
    set "INPUT=!INPUT:"=!"
    set VAR!COUNT!=!INPUT!
    echo Variable !COUNT! = !VAR!!COUNT!
  )
)
```

My expected output is

```
Variable 1 = set text inside quotes to VAR1
Variable 2 = set text inside quotes to VAR2
```

but what I get is

```
Variable 2 = 2
Variable 3 = 3
Variable 4 = 4
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show us your existing code.

Comment: Findstr doesn't iterate, it filters input lines which meet given criteria, an enclosing for /f might iterate on the filtered lines. There are plenty of examples for this day by day here on [SO].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took your code and fixed it up.
In particular:

- I switched the `findstr` to find all lines that do not match `HEADER`
- I used arrays to store the variables.

It may need some minor tweaks to get it exactly as you want it, but I think I've given you a working outline.

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set COUNT=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('findstr /i /v HEADER data.txt') do (
  set "INPUT=%%a"
  set /A COUNT=!COUNT!+1
  set "INPUT=!INPUT:DATA:=!"
  set VAR[!COUNT!]=!INPUT!
  call echo Variable !COUNT! = %%VAR[!COUNT!]%%
)
```

**Output**:

```
Variable 1 =   "set text inside quotes to VAR1"
Variable 2 =   "set text inside quotes to VAR2"
Variable 3 = DATA (etc.)
```

---

To match lines that have leading spaces, use switches:

```
findstr /V /R /C:"^ *HEADER"
```

The regular expression means:

```
^       : Beginning of line
[space] : a literal space
*       : the previous character (space) repeated as many times as needed
HEADER  : the text to find after leading spaces
```

The switches mean:

- `/R`  Use Regular Expressions
- `/C:` Use this search-string
- `/V`  Show all lines that do NOT match this expression.

Comment: Thanks, abelenky.  I see what you did and think I finally get why the FINDSTR command goes in the FOR line and not the ECHO line.  Looking forward to trying this out on a larger scale and assigning the CMD file to a Directory Opus toolbar button.

Comment: In line 4, I know I can use the `FINDSTR /b` switch to look only at the beginning of the input line for the word "header," which I would like to limit the search to in case the word "header" appears in a `DATA` line. The /b switch, however, fails to kill the `HEADER` lines if they happen to have a leading space. Is there a way to get `FINDSTR` to ignore any spaces at the start of a line?